# IE8 doesn't work

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I'm using Ajax call for API in Sharepoint 2010. I don't have that much Access to edit master page.

**Error: No Transport**

I also use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">   
 <head>  
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<!--<title>WiFi Home</title>-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>   
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src=".../SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>      
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">  -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@1.5.4/src/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@1.5.4/extras/loadingoverlay_progress/loadingoverlay_progress.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uninstall ie8...all good

Comment: What do you mean uninstall IE8? We have 4000+ SharePoint users .

Comment: Effective January 12, 2016, Internet Explorer 8 is no longer supported on any client or server version of Windows

Answer (score 0):

What is your detailed error when using IE8, I see in your code, it is referencing the Js library, no logic code.